# Assignation inside IIF possible, why doesn't it work?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iif

Work :

```
publicity.Target = IIF(radioTarget1.Checked, "_blank", "_self").toString
```

Doesn't work :

```
IIF(radioTarget1.Checked, publicity.Target = "_blank", publicity.Target = "_self")
```

Why isn't the second option working?

Comment: I don't see how that first line even compiles, yet you say it works, somehow.  Have you looked at the new If operator?

Comment: Oh, a simple rewrite error, I had forgot the IIF (now added). And now, yes I did. But it seems we are still on VB2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not assignments you are doing inside the function call, it's comparisons.

It does the same as:

```
Dim result As Boolean
If radioTarget1.Checked Then
  result = (publicity.Target = "_blank")
Else
  result = (publicity.Target = "_self")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

IIF is a function, not a language feature.

The second two parameters are objects that are potential return values of the function... not a block of code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx